# function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I made a relation of criminal cases in a police station.

```
CREATE TABLE C_CASE
(
Case_ID int,
Case_Details varchar(255),
Case_Status varchar(255),
Section_Of_Law varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO C_CASE
VALUES(333,'Hit and Run','Pending','304(A)');

INSERT INTO C_CASE
VALUES(444,'Robbery','Closed','392');

INSERT INTO C_CASE
VALUES(555,'Extortion','Pending','384');

INSERT INTO C_CASE
VALUES(222,'Murder','Closed','302');
```

I created a function which will return the number of Cases which are pending.
but I get an error. The function is :

```
create function NumOfCases(@statustype varchar(255)) returns varchar(255)
as
begin
return
(
    select count(Case_Status) from C_CASE where Case_Status=@statustype
)
end
```

**QUERY:**

```
   select  from dbo.NumOfCases('Pending');
```

I keep getting the error:

**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The error message comes from that there is nothing between `select` and `from` in your query. If you wanted to select from the function result you would need a table value function. You have a scalar value function so it returns just a value. Call it for example using `select dbo.NumOfCases('Pending');`

Comment: @Guffa I have called it exactly the same way as you told, but it just shows Incorrect Syntax.

Comment: According to the error message you have at least 21 lines of code in the query. Are you sure that the error is in that statement?

Comment: It's solved. Thank you. However, it was that line of code only as I cross checked with it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the return type of your function from varchar to integer using `RETURNS int` as you are trying to return a count.

The way you should call the function from sql is like this

```
select db.NumOfCases('Pending') as YourCount
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here. You did not name your column in your function. Then in your query you didn't specify anything to select. Since your query is a scalar function you don't use FROM. I would suggest however that you don't want a scalar function at all . The performance of them is horrible. A inline table valued function would be far better. Something like this.

```
create function NumOfCases
(
    @statustype varchar(255)
) returns table 
as
return
    select count(Case_Status) as StatusCount
    from C_CASE 
    where Case_Status = @statustype
```

Then to use this you could do something like this.

```
Select StatusCount
from NumOfCases('Pending')
```

You might also consider normalizing the status values. I would suggest using a Status table to hold the text values of your statuses. Then you have just the StatusID in your Case table.

Comment: your answer resulted in the error " Invalid object name 'dbo.NumOfCases' "

Comment: Did you run ONLY the create function code or did you run both sets of code at the same time? I suspect that is what happened which would cause that error to occur. Either run this as two batches or put a GO before the final select statement.

Comment: I've run all the code. The problem was on the 21st Line, which is now solved.

Comment: Ummm ok??? The code I posted has 9 lines so not sure how my code had an error on the 21st line. I guess you have solved your problem now? I hope for your system performance that you at least consider not using scalar functions for this type of thing.

Comment: Actually I was trying out different things. So tried to mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a count of something use Integer for your return type.

```
create function NumOfCases(@statustype varchar(255)) 
returns INT
as
begin
  Declare @RtnValue INT;

    select @RtnValue = count(Case_Status) from C_CASE where Case_Status=@statustype
  return @RtnValue
end
```

Comment: and how do I call the function with input parameter?

Comment: @pratikwatwani `Select dbo.NumOfCases('Pending')`